# Comma or semi colon?

Tags: grammar, commas, semicolons

In the following sentence, should I use a comma or a semi-colon after same?

> The live and staging set-ups are the same, combining PHP, MySQL and
>   Apache to power the websites.

or

> The live and staging set-ups are the same; combining PHP, MySQL and Apache
>   to power the websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence (using a comma rather than a semicolon) is more correct.

However, you will see the second semi-often. The issue in this case is that there are other commas in the sentence, not used for clause separation.  Many people will sometimes use a semicolon in this case to make it stand out more from the other commas, which are just used for enumerating a list, rather than separating a subordinate clause.